# Global scope procedures cannot be generic? Is there a technical reason for this restriction?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe6

Why is it that using generic types in a global procedure is not permitted. For example:

```
  procedure Foo<T>(bar : T);
```

Compiler Error: E2530 Type parameters not allowed on global procedure or function

Yet it is acceptable as a class method

```
TFoo = class(TObject)
public
  class procedure Foo<T>(bar : T);
end;
```

That's obviously my workaround, but I am interested in whether there an actual technical reason for the restriction.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I am happy to edit my question if anything is unclear.

Comment: Freepascal has support for global generic procedures/functions.

Comment: Only the designers know the reason why this limitation exists. It is not documented, or publicly stated anywhere. And the main designer who could answer this definitively (Allen Bauer) is no longer with the company.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no technical reason why procedures at global scope could not be generic.

If the designers wanted to implement this, then it could be done.

Comment: Not sure why this would be downvoted, seeing as it's accurate, concise and answers the question.  No pleasing some people, I guess.

Comment: @MartynA Perils of answering a question which is probably closeable for being opinion based

Comment: Well if it makes you feel any better, neither of your downvotes were from me. But I have no idea why you would think this opinion based. There is either a technical reason why it could not be done, or it wasn't done because they thought it bad/dangerous, or it wasn't done because they had other priorities. You are entirely free to be disinterested in the answer to this question, but I found it a curious omission and wondered whether it indicated something about the implementation of generics in Delphi that I was misunderstanding. In any case, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @AdamG The question title, and the part of the body that I removed in my edit, are opinion based. And now I've edited out the opinion based part of the title.